# Android MP3 Player, play/pause button not working

Tags: android, mp3, playback, pause

I'm following an Udemy class on making a MP3 player like Spotify.  I'm new to Android studio, and know/understand very little.  The class is a bit older, and uses an older version of Android Studio from 2 years ago, so this might be part of the problem.  I can hear the MP3 when I first start debugging, and the button will also change from play to pause, however, it is unresponsive to any clicking.  I hear the sound it's been clicked, but it never changes status or pauses the audio.  Thank you for the assistance, it's greatly appreciated!

```
    ***************** Main Activity.java ************************

package live.regionradio.regionradio;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.AudioManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static FloatingActionButton btnPlayPause;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnPlayPause = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        String url = "https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3";
        if (Player.player == null)
            new Player();
        Player.player.playStream(url);
    }

    public static void flipPlayPauseButton (boolean isPlaying) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            btnPlayPause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        }
        else {
            btnPlayPause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }


    }

***************** Player.java ************************

    package live.regionradio.regionradio;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import java.io.IOException;


    public class Player {

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        public static Player player;
        String url = "";

        public Player() {
            this.player = this;
        }

        public void playStream(String url) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    private MediaPlayer mp;


                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        this.mp = mp;
                        playPlayer();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    private MediaPlayer mp;

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        this.mp = mp;
                        MainActivity.flipPlayPauseButton(false);
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void pausePlayer () {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                MainActivity.flipPlayPauseButton(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTION", "Failed to pause media player.");
            }
        }

        public void playPlayer () {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                MainActivity.flipPlayPauseButton(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTION", "Failed to play media player.");
            }
        }

        public void togglePlayer () {
            try  {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    pausePlayer();
                else
                    playPlayer();
            }
            catch   (Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception", "failed to toggle media player.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        }
```

I believe this is exactly what happens after you click the button, namely - nothing. You should put something inside that function. You override the onClick function and leave it empty, so anything you would want to happen after clicking, you should put inside it.

Your "togglePlayer()" is never used, perhaps that's what you should put in the listener.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but I'm not sure how to add the code to make this work.  Would you be so kind to write the code needed?  Thank you!